# When do the struts/custom tags get resolved if they are inside javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts-1

I am experiencing a very strange problem. I have a jsp page which has one javascript method. This method contains a lot of Struts and custom tags. This method iterate on few lists and then create rows and columns dynamically and add them to a table.
This method also creates few links to other javascript methods on those newly added rows and columns.

Now the problem is that this method is called on document ready and it takes a lot of time and page is taking minutes to get rendered completely.
Strange thing is that even if I don't call this method then also page takes a lot of time. But if I call it after removing the code inside it then page is rendered very fast.

So I am not able to understand when do those tags get resolved from server- on page load or before the response is sent by server?

Why does this method make my page slow even if I don't call this method?

What is the standard way to tackle this problem?

Adding sample code to check:

```
<s:set var="indexCount" value="0" />
                    <logic:iterator value="#someParentList" var="company" status="statusL">

                        <logic:iterator value="#childLIst" var="employee" status="statusB" >    
                            empBalHtml += '<tr>';
                            empBalHtml += '  <td class="flag" rowspan="2" >';
                            empBalHtml +=        getString(function(){/*!<s:checkbox name="enrolActivity.schBalempAllocationSave[%{#indexCount}].chk" />*/});     
                            empBalHtml +=        getString(function(){/*!<s:textfield value="%{#employee.billDate}"  fieldId="emp_ALLOCATION_SECTION" format="date" calendar="false" style="display:none" name="enrolActivity.schBalempAllocationSave[%{#indexCount}].schBalempTotalAppliedBillDate" />*/});
                            empBalHtml += '      <s:hidden name="enrolActivity.schBalempAllocationSave[%{#indexCount}].empIdKey" value="%{#employee.empIdKey}" ></s:hidden>';
                            empBalHtml += '      <s:hidden name="enrolActivity.schBalempAllocationSave[%{#indexCount}].primarySecondary" value="%{#employee.pmtStream}" ></s:hidden>';
                            empBalHtml += '      <s:hidden name="enrolActivity.schBalempAllocationSave[%{#indexCount}].employeeId" value="%{#employee.employeeId}" ></s:hidden>';
                            empBalHtml += '      <s:hidden name="enrolActivity.schBalempAllocationSave[%{#indexCount}].position" value="%{#indexCount + 1}" ></s:hidden>';
                            empBalHtml += '  </td>';
                            empBalHtml += '  <td rowspan="2" nowrap="nowrap">';
                            empBalHtml += '      <s:a id="empId-%{#statusB.index}"  fieldId="emp_ALLOCATION_SECTION" href="javascript:$.nav.urlForward(CTX_ROOT + \"/empDetails_load.do?empIDKey=%{#company.empIdKey}\")">${company.emp.empId}</s:a>';
                            empBalHtml += '      <s:if test="enrolActivityFlags.secondaryPresent" >&nbsp;(<s:label name="enrolActivity.empBalances[%{#indexCount}].pmtStream" value="%{#employee.pmtStream}"  fieldId="emp_ALLOCATION_SECTION"/>) </s:if>';
                            empBalHtml += '  </td>';

                            empBalHtml += '  <td class="numeric">';
                            empBalHtml +=        getString(function(){/*!<s:label value="0" format="currency" currencyCode="${enrolActivity.currency}" fieldId="emp_ALLOCATION_SECTION"/>*/});
                            empBalHtml += '  </td>';
                            empBalHtml += '</tr>';     

                            <s:set name="indexCount" value="%{#indexCount + 1}"/>
                         </logic:iterator>

                    </logic:iterator>

                    $("#someRow").after(empBalHtml);
```

Comment: Iterating lists inside of the javascript will create lot of javascript code which will be executed after executed later using either javascript or jquery document ready. If you are calling method or not, still the generated will be there in the browser. Instead of generating dynamic rows using javascript use struts iterate tags to create elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this method make my page slow even if I don't call this method?

Because every Struts2 tag is translated into HTML (eg. `<s:select>`,`<s:textarea>`) or plain text (eg. `<s:property/>`, `<s:date/>`) **before** the page is sent to the browser.

If you inject those tags into javascript blocks, however, remember to set `escapeJavascript="true"` or you'll risk to break your page loading, and will be vulnerable to javascript injection.

> What is the standard way to tackle this problem?

#### >  [Pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination#Pagination_in_web_content) <

If you have 1 million of records, no matter if you append them through HTML, javascript or whatever, you need to load and render only 10 / 50 / 100 of them, not 1 million.

Comment: My half of the page is shown very fast but other half takes a lot of time. Does that mean that page is coming from server to client in pieces? or Javascript is coming last from server to browser? So when that code is translated it gets slower

Comment: around 100 records

Comment: yes its taking a lot of time, I have added few lines from that method to question itself. You can assume method contains 5-6 times of the sample code given.

Comment: JSTL mixed with OGNL mixed with JSP EL... maybe something is disturbing something else. Try converting everything to OGNL and struts tags, and if the problem persists, try reducing the lines until it stops being so slow, then you'll get the culprit

Answer (score 2):

JSP and (custom) struts tags are rendered on the server side, Javascript is in the most struts environments always client side (browser). Thus your browser is probably slow, because you are producing huge javascript code on the server side, which the browser has to run. If you invoke this method always an document ready it will run every time your browser visits the page. Or maybe it is that huge, that the transfer time affected.

Example: Following JSP and the HTML result for the browser:

```xml
...
<script>
var myvar = "<s:text name='foo.bar'/>";    
</script>
...
```

Result for the browser, which the javascript engine in the browser has to run:

```xml
...
<script>
var myvar = "My Foo Bar translation";
</script>
...
```

Take a look for example with Firefox and there "Inspector" (right click on the page) and look for the script tab or inspect the DOM.